# Is it possible to center chemical equations by the arrow?

Tags: equations, arrows, chemistry, mhchem

[image]

I created this reaction equation with:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, toc=flat]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=6pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{spacing}{1.25}
        \ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}\\
        \ce{SiCl4 + 2H2O -> SiO2 + 4HCl}\\
        Gesamtreaktion: \ce{2H2 + O2 + SiCl4 -> SiO2 + 4HCl}
    \end{spacing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to center the equations, so that the arrows are positioned directly beneath one and another?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `reactions` module from the `chemmacros` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `align*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\ce{2 H2 + O2} &\ce{-> 2 H2O} \\
\ce{SiCl4 + 2 H2O} &\ce{-> SiO2 + 4 HCl} \\
\text{Gesamtreaktion:~} \ce{2 H2 + O2 + SiCl4} &\ce{-> SiO2 + 4 HCl}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could combine a few \ce's. See chapter "Aligning Equations" in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[modules={reactions}]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions*}
  2 H2 + O2 &-> 2 H2O \\
  SiCl4 + 2 H2O &-> SiO2 + 4 HCl \\
  \text{Gesamtreaktion:~} 2 H2 + O2 + SiCl4 &-> SiO2 + 4 HCl
\end{reactions*}

\end{document}
```